# How can i get id in base_url or site_url?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

im having problem in getting id in site or base url

its my models

```
function getDataLogin($id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where('mstUser_2', array('nik' => $id))->row_array();
}
```

and it my controller

```
function editAccount($id)
{
    $data['log'] = $this->LoginModels->getDataLogin($id);
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('login/changeProfile', $data, true);
    $this->parser->parse(TEMPLATE . '/content_admin', $data);
}
```

and its view i call the id, but there is not identified $log and non-object the nik

```
 <div class="pull-left">
                                     <a href="<?php echo site_url('administrator/login/editAccount/'. $log->nik); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Change</a>
                                 </div>
```

what i missed ?

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting it as row_array() but are trying to access it as an object.

`$log->nik` should be `$log['nik']`

Comment: but still not working, Undefined variable: log

Comment: if you've defined `log` in your controller, naturally it wouldn't be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can try get the link and explode the value. Saya indo juga mas.